# xcode 6 GM crash after launch

Tags: xcode6, xcode6gm

I use OS 10.10, Xcode 6 GM, my project write by swift(& Objective-C).

The project can run with Xcode 6-beta7.

```
Process:               Xcode [7267]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.0 (6299)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6299000000000000~8
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [7267]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2014-09-10 17:25:38.697 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10 (14A343f)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        587D71D4-C53F-50BF-625D-CF092416EEDC


Time Awake Since Boot: 12000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        14  Dispatch queue: shared-compile-command-queue :: NSOperation 0x7f887f8aa900 (QOS: UTILITY)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6A313
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDELanguageSupport/IDELanguageSupport-6233/XCLanguageSupport/XCSwiftCommandOutputParser.m:222
Details:  (subcommand) should not be nil.
Object:   <XCSwiftCommandOutputParser: 0x7f887cde4740>
Method:   -handleCommandExitedMessage:didSignal:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f887ff8c130>{number = 14, name = (null)}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010696cf0a -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010572bbaf _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010572be9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000011470d6ce -[XCSwiftCommandOutputParser handleCommandExitedMessage:didSignal:error:] (in XCLanguageSupport)
  4  0x000000011470c3b9 -[XCSwiftCommandOutputParser handleMessage:error:] (in XCLanguageSupport)
  5  0x000000011470d7d9 -[XCSwiftCommandOutputParser writeBytes:length:] (in XCLanguageSupport)
  6  0x0000000110c6cd70 -[XCLineBufferedOutputStream writeBytes:length:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x0000000110cfb5a0 -[XCWorkQueueCommandSubprocessInvocation handleOutputBytes:length:] (in DevToolsCore)
  8  0x0000000110cfd490 -[XCWorkQueueCommandLocalSubprocessInvocation handleOutputFileDescriptorActivity] (in DevToolsCore)
  9  0x0000000110d5abac -[Xcode3BuildTask main] (in DevToolsCore)
 10  0x00007fff8ec0b0ac -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] (in Foundation)
 11  0x00007fff8ec0acb3 __NSOQSchedule_f (in Foundation)
 12  0x00007fff92116d53 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 13  0x00007fff9211a3f7 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff9211bf4c _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15  0x00007fff9211978b _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 16  0x00007fff92128002 _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 17  0x00007fff9a3366cb _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 18  0x00007fff9a3344a1 start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
((subcommand)) != nil
```

Comment: 试一试将product name改为英文会不会有问题？

Comment: @yudun1989 Thanks! That's the problem! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem, I temporarily solved that by change product name to english. Seems it's a bug of Xcode GM version.

Answer (score 5):

Just delete all your xcode simulators derived Data, you can find derived data path at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, woalaa... crash issue solved.

Comment: That absolutely saved my bacon, right before a really important meeting!

Answer (score 2):

Simply changing the projects parent file name in Finder fixed it.

1) Change the file name of project.xcodeproj parent (Changing just .xcodeproj name did not work for me)

2) Open xcode

3) Close xcode

4) Change name back

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. It seems to be related to bridging headers. Removing the file (BridgingHeader.h for me) from the projet allow to open the project without crashing immediately !)
Investigating…

Update:
It seems that it was due to  a "•" character in the project path !
Renaming the directory containing my projects from "• projects" to "projects" seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: But after deleting the BridgingHeader , the project won't compile... It makes me crazy...How to solve it .

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. No special characters in path name.

Simply changing the project name file in Finder solves the problem.
Another way that worked for me was to change the location project folder to my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to reappear every weekend for me!  I have tried the other answers below with some success however, they do not always work.  Then I stumbled across this post.

https://github.com/kattrali/deriveddata-exterminator/issues/20

> Comment from bdsinger:
>   I get the crash in Xcode 6.1 GM whenever I resize the project window
>   on external display at work after using built-in LCD display on retina
>   mbpro all wkend. Crash report reveals the plugin as the cause.
>   Uninstalled, crash went away. Would be more specific if I had the
>   time, sorry. But nevertheless, thanks for the plugin and the effort!

It turns out to be an issue between my laptop, thunderbolt display, and Hyperdocks.  Throughout the week I use my laptop at various places however, on the weekends I use my thunderbolt display.

Unplug your laptop from your external monitor, open your Xcode project (Yah! no crash), then reconnect it to your external monitor.

Note: Hyperdocks is a [paid] program that takes the best features of Windows 7 and integrates them into your mac.  Such as resizing windows by snapping to the sides.
Hence the crashed caused by resizing Xcode window using this plugin and swapping displays.